# Get a version within a text file

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get an application version from Version.txt file looping through a bunch of folders. It's not a big deal by itself but the problem is that there are a lot of other stuff in these files.

Examples:

```
'1.0.0.1'

'Version - 0.11.0.11'

'ApplicationName - 1.0.12.89'

'Definitely some useful information.
 ApplicationName - 1.0.13.0'
```

The file *always ends with the version* but there are no other correlations. The length of the version is different every time because there can be different number of digits between dots.
It drives me crazy. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi, can you please edit your question to include the code you have tried so far?

Comment: well, if its the last, get the last string and parse it?

Comment: If your input always has the format of any of the four different inputs you listed above, then you could get the version number by running `($version_text -split "-" | select -last 1).Trim()`. It should work with your other examples as well. Here `$version_text` contains your input string, i.e. contents of Version.txt.

Comment: everybody seems to love regex questions here ;))))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution 1

```
((get-content  "C:\temp\file1.txt" -Tail 1) -split "-|'")[1].Trim()


#Code decomposed for explain

#get last row of file
$lastrowfile=get-content  "C:\temp\file1.txt" -Tail 1

#split last row with - or ' as separator
$arraystr=$lastrowfile -split "-|'"

#take element 1 of split and trim final string
$arraystr[1].Trim()
```

Comment: This does work perfectly but there is always a spacebar at the beginning of the resutling string. May I ask to explain your code a little?

Comment: i have modify my code for space and explain my code ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've shorten it to this: (Get-Content $VersionFilePath -Last 1).Split("-|'")[1].Trim()

Comment: Hm. It was not so simple. I've changed it to:
Try
                {
                ($Version = Get-Content $VersionFilePath -Last 1).Split("-|'")[1].Trim()
                }
            Catch
                {
                ($Version = Get-Content $VersionFilePath -Last 1).Split("-|'")[0].Trim()
                }

Answer (score 0):

Because the version is always at the last line, use the `Get-Content` cmdlet with the `-tail` parameter to read only the last line. Then select the version using the `Select-String` cmdlet and a [regex](/questions/tagged/regex):

```
(Get-Content 'Your_File_Path.txt' -Tail 1 | Select-String "(?<=- ).*(?=')").Matches.Value
```

**Output:**

```
1.0.13.0
```

Comment: Thank you Martin but it doesn't work for some reason. No errors though.

Answer (score 0):

This would search the file for all lines that appear to have a version number on them, take the very last line with a match in that file, and return just the version number.

```
$content = Get-Content 'path\to\your\version.txt'
$regex = [regex]"\d+(\.\d+)+"

# Grab the last line in the version file that appears to have a version number
$versionLine = $content -match $regex | Select-Object -Last 1

if ($versionLine) {
    # Parse and return the version
    $regex.Match($versionLine).Value
}
else {
    Write-Warning 'No version found.'
}
```

That works with all of the version numbers you posted, and would work if the version number appears to be at the end of the file, but there's additional whitespace afterward, etc.

Comment: Weird. Does it throw an error? Which version of PowerShell are you running? I tested this on v5.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 2

```
((get-content  "C:\temp\file1.txt" | where {$_ -like "*ApplicationName*"} | select -Last 1) -split "-|'")[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use get-content and then split :

```
((get-content  "C:\test.txt" | where {$_ -like "*ApplicationName*"} | select -Last 1) -split "-|'")[1]
```